# MindbodyApi iOS app throws a "201" error code

Tags: ios, mindbody

While implementing MindbodyApi's soap services particularly **[ClientServices](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Develop/ClientService)** i continuously got an error code of 201 .. Error code 201 is [nested error](https://support.mindbodyonline.com/hc/en-us/articles/203267433-API-Error-Codes).

Comment: where in your code was the error? post snippets so people can see

Comment: Mindbody soap response throws that error code 201 .. there is no error in the code.

Comment: 201 means something failed, you need to identify where this error is being generated and review that code. if there were no errors in the code, you wouldn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have been told by mindbody support that this error happens when fields does not match with mindbody online.

Hope it helps :)